# Don't know how to avoid null pointer exception when activity is recreated after user used other apps

Tags: android, sql, nullpointerexception, oncreate

The app works perfectly if the user stays in the app and we have tested it fairly well for logic.  However, when the user use other apps and the activity is destroyed by the system, the onCreate is called again. When the `onCreate` is called, I get a null pointer reference:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_play_golf);

        // set variables
        db = new PMDBHelper(this);
        if(!db.CheckDBOpen())
            db.OpenDB();

        VariableDeclaration()
```

The null pointer is called at the db.CheckDBOpen().

in my PMDPHelper class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public void OpenDB() {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int intDBVersion = db.getVersion();
    }

public void CloseDB() {
    db.close();
}

public Boolean CheckDBOpen() {
    if (db.isOpen()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

The error I get is the following:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to incoke virtual
>   method 'boolean android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.isOpen()'on a
>   null object reference.

What I don't understand is that I am initialising db before accessing it both during the normal operation but also when the app receives focus again.

**Alternative attempt to fix issues**

I normally set my activity's orientation to a fixed orientation.  The one in this activity was set to portrait.  As the activity gets recreated during an orientation change, I've tried not to specify a fixed orientation.  When I change the orientation of the screen, the activity works perfect.  The onCreate fires again and I get no errors.  The error only occurs when the user comes back to the app and after the system destroyed the app.

Could you please help me solve this issue?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: it´s not that your `db` variable is null, it´s that the `checkDBOpen` method runs into a null objects at any Point in it´s `isOpen` method.

Comment: Looks like there is a problme when you open the db, thats why your db variable is null.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question to show the relevant code but cannot see where the null pointer will arise

Comment: @Jean could you edit what Class `db` represents in `PMDBHelper`. It seems that it is null after you call `db = new PMDBHelper(this);`

Comment: public class PMDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: OK, I got to answer my own question - the db field was not properly initialised once the program returned.  Once I initialised it properly, the problem was solved